# Limit points of $\{e^x:x \in \mathbb R \}$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to determine the limit points of $\{e^x:x \in \mathbb R \}$.  I thought that it was $[0,\infty)$ at first because that's the range of the function, but that obviously doesn't make any sense because infinity doesn't have a limit. Is it possible that the there are no limit points for this sequence?

Comment: $[0,\infty)$ is  the right answer. I don' understand why you think that this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You were right in your assumption that the limit points are $[0 , \infty )$. To see this, for any $c \in (0 , \infty )$, we know we can simply let $x = ln (c)$ so that $e^x = c$. So the constant sequence $\{ ln(c) \}_{i>0}$ satisfies $\lim e^{ln(c)} = c$. Now if we take $c = 0$, consider the sequence $\{ ln(\frac{1}{i}) \}_{i > 0}$. Then
$$
\lim\limits_{i \to \infty} e^{ln(\frac{1}{i})} = \lim\limits_{i \to \infty} \frac{1}{i} = 0
$$
Note that our answer does not contain the 'point' infinity. Any sequence contained within the set $\{ e^x \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ that approaches infinity will diverge. When speaking of the real numbers, we cannot refer to infinity as a point because it is not a real number. Infinity is just notation for an unbounded limit; which is why when we take a limit as $i$ approaches infinity we do not just evaluate 'at' infinity.

See this wikipedia page for a more in depth look at the mathematical definition of infinity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity#Mathematics

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that there are no limit points for this sequence?

This is *not* a "sequence". The set $\{e^x:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is exactly $S=(0,\infty)$, i.e., the set of positive real numbers. So you are asking what the [limit points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) of the set $S$ are. This is a concept in topology. Although closely related to the sequence of real numbers, you are *not* taking "limit" of the set $S$.

You should check by *definition* that the set of limit points of $S$ is $[0,\infty)$.